# using viewForHeaderInSection method in iOS application

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a grouped UITableView with multiple segments. I would like to have a button below each segment in the footer that when pushed would take the user to a different view controller (with some options - the data-model to be loaded in the destination VC). The two ViewControllers in question are managed by a UINavigationController.

I am not sure what the best way to achieve this is...

I have tried:

1. Creating each UIView (with the button) in IB and trying to add the view to a section footer there. I do not think this is possible.
2. Creating the UIViews purely in code, add then adding them to each of the section footers. This is working fine however the issue here is that I then cannot wire in my segue & segue identifier in IB. I am using the prepareForSegue method to send the correct data-model to the destination VC (depending on which segment footer button is pushed) so I require this. Is there an alternative here, can I trigger send my data-model in some other way?

Thanks, James

Comment: I think you mean to say "I have a grouped `UITableView` with multiple sections. I would like to have a button below each section in the footer...".

Comment: I did mean this. Thanks rmaddy!

Comment: Feel free to edit your question to make it more correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1 is possible.

Pull your customer view out of the nib as you would any other custom view [Load View from Nib](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2578-loading-a-nib-file-programmatically-objective-c/); then add it using:

```
- (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)headerViewForSection:(NSInteger)section
```

**edit** Sorry, didn't mean to imply that #2 isn't also viable.

```
- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier

// like this:
UIViewController * vc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TheNewView"]
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using option 2, Create your segue from the view controller instead of from a specific view or button. Give it a meaningful identifier, then in the action method for your button, call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` on your view controller. You can pass in any object you like as the view controller, including the index path or an NSNumber holding the section identifier, so you can access this in prepareForSegue and use the appropriate parts of your data model.